# import html template in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-routing, webpack-3, typescript-2.5

I'm trying to `import` my html template so that webpack will recognize them and include them when I build. (`webpack -d`)

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2709) I should do this

```
declare module '*.html' {
    const _: string;
    export default _;
}
```

Then `import template from './myTemplate.html';` should work.

But it doesn't quite do the trick.

```
import template from './myTemplate.html';
console.log(template); // undefined
```

However this *"works"*

```
import * as template from './myTemplate.html';
console.log(template); // <p>Hello world!</p>
```

Very strange.

But now this doesn't work

```
$routeProvider.when("/test", {
    template: template, // ERROR! template is typeof(*.html) expected string
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: "$ctrl"
});
```

However if I change my *.html module to

```
declare module '*.html' {
    const _: string;
    export = _; // changed this
}
```

I can now do

```
import * as template from './myTemplate.html';

$routeProvider.when("/test", {
    template: template, // Great success!
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: "$ctrl"
});
```

It works, but why doesn't `import template from './myTemplate.html';` work? **What am I doing wrong** as the others in the GitHub issue seemed to get it to work like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, in order to use `import template from './myTemplate.html';` you need to use `export default` syntax.

Because of the fact that webpack is the one that handles `html` imports it [doesn't do](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/blob/master/index.js#L137-L143) export default by default.

But you can [configure](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#export-formats) your `html-loader` to use export default.

Comment: Aha, so it's actually a webpack issue and not a typescript issue.

Comment: it's not an issue :]
A matter of configuration.